# Laravel uploading files and extension issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to make store method where placing 2 different type of files - .pdf and .step.
First issue, that .pdf file is moved to wanted directory, but in database storing temporary location like C:\xampp\tmp\phpAA39.tmp etc...
At the start was same issue with .step files, but i tried to update my code and now it's not even storing path to database. Both files are placing to storage/models and storage/drawings how it should be, but .step files are saving as .txt by some reasons.
ProductController:

```
public function store(Order $order, Request $request){

   $this->validate($request, [
    'name'=>'required',
    'drawing'=>'nullable|file',
    '_3d_file'=>'nullable|file',
    'quantity'=>'integer',
    'unit_price'=>'required',
    'discount'=>'nullable'
   ]);
   if (request('drawing')) {
    request('drawing')->store('drawings');
   }
   if (request('_3d_file')) {
    request('_3d_file')->store('models');
   }
//    dd(request()->all());
   $order->products()->create($request->all());
   session()->flash('product-created', 'New product was added successfully');    
   return redirect()->route('order', $order);
    }
```

**Update:**
Figured out, how to solve an extension and temp location stuff... but still don't understand why on my store method does not storing 3dfile path while with drawing is ok and code is exactly the same. Also on update method it stores path with no errors. Any thoughts?

```
    public function store(Order $order){
    $inputs = request()->validate([
    'name'=>'required',
    'drawing'=>'file',
    '_3d_file'=>'file',
    'quantity'=>'integer',
    'unit_price'=>'required',
    'discount'=>'nullable'
   ]);

   if (request('drawing')) {
    $filename = request('drawing')->getClientOriginalName();
    $inputs['drawing'] = request('drawing')->storeAs('drawings', $filename);

   }
   if (request('_3d_file')) {
       $filename = request('_3d_file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $inputs['_3d_file'] = request('_3d_file')->storeAs('models', $filename);   
    
   }
    //dd($inputs['_3d_file']);
   $order->products()->create($inputs);
   
   session()->flash('product-created', 'New product was added successfully');    
   return redirect()->route('order', $order);
    }
```

update

```
public function update(Product $product){
        $inputs = request()->validate([
            'name'=>'required',
            'drawing'=>'nullable|file',
            '_3d_file'=>'nullable|file',
            'quantity'=>'integer',
            'unit_price'=>'required',
            'discount'=>'nullable'
        ]);
        if (request('drawing')) {
            $filename = request('drawing')->getClientOriginalName();
           $inputs['drawing'] = request('drawing')->storeAs('drawings', $filename);
           $product->drawing = $inputs['drawing'];
        }

        if (request('_3d_file')) {
            $filename = request('_3d_file')->getClientOriginalName();
            $inputs['_3d_file'] = request('_3d_file')->storeAs('models', $filename);
            $product->_3d_file = $inputs['_3d_file'];
         }

        $product->name = $inputs['name'];
        $product->quantity = $inputs['quantity'];
        $product->unit_price = $inputs['unit_price'];
        $product->discount = $inputs['discount'];

        $product->save();
        session()->flash('product-updated', 'The product was updated successfully');
        return redirect()->route('product', $product);
    }
```

Comment: Change the line to `$request->drawing->store('drawings');`

Comment: Not worked, still same

Comment: Try to use 3d_file without '_' in the start name your model.

Comment: Well in order to use name - 3d_file, i had to use _ at start, because variable can't start with number